# Samsung KNOX enabling KIOSK Mode with package name does not work

Tags: android, samsung-knox

I am trying to use KIOSK Mode Sample app on Galaxy S4 (Android 4.4.2). All functionality works fine except for this method:

```
public void enableKioskMode(String kioskPackage)
```

the KIOSKReceiver gets the ACTION_ENABLE_KIOSK_MODE_RESULT message, but the KIOSK mode is not actually started.

What I need to achieve is KIOSK mode starting my custom application on pressing home button. Perhaps I'm just using the wrong method?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say what's going on with so few details, but there are some requirements to be able to enable kiosk with samsung knox :

1. Your app must be [device administrator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)
2. Your knox license must have been activated for your device administrator app (be careful, this is an asynchronous process and it sometimes requires user interaction. i.e. user must approve the license if he didn't do it yet)
3. Your device administrator app must have the permission : `android.permission.sec.MDM_KIOSK_MODE`

Note that the kiosk mode with samsung knox disable the home key. (i.e. it do not redirect you to your kiosk app.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what the Result Code is?
Is there something useful in this website:
https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/api-kioskmodeiskioskmodeenabled-always-returning-false